# Moving git refs to new directory

Tags: git

Is there a way to move refs from one directory (e.g. refs/tags) to another directory (i.e. refs/old_tags) without resorting to mucking around in the .git directory?  I only want to move some refs, not all of them.

This is mainly to clean up some stuff from an svn conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want using the `git update-ref` command.  Assuming that you have a tag `mytag` and you want to move it into `.git/refs/old_tags/mytag`, you can do this:

```
git update-ref refs/old_tags/mytag mytag
git tag -d mytag
```

And now `git show-ref` shows:

```
...commit... refs/old_tags/mytag
```